# Get Jquery variables as php variable with a submitt button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I´ve a table (3 rows) where users can select the three variables of a row with one click on a "select button." I need these three variables as php variables to continue working with them.

**the table**

```
echo '<table class="formatHTML5" id="myTable">';

$count = 0;
foreach($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $key => $item) {
        $count = $count + 1;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="p"><span>';
        echo  $count;
        echo '</td></span>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $item['name'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $item['realm']['name'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  $item['level'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo  '<button class="btnSelect">Select</button>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
}

        echo '</table>';
```

**Table HTML Output**

```
<table class="formatHTML5" id="myTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="p"><span>1</span></td>
<td>User100</td>
<td>Malygos</td>
<td>1</td>
<td><button class="btnSelect">Select</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**jquery script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
    $("#myTable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
         // get the current row
         var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 
         
         var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html(); // get current row 1st table cell TD value
         var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html(); // get current row 2nd table cell TD value
         var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").html(); // get current row 3rd table cell  TD value
      
         var data1=col1;
         var data2=col2;
         var data3=col3;
          
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-callback.php",
       data: data1, data2, data3;
       success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
    });
     
});

});
```

I want to have the variables of each table row as php variables after the user has **clicked** on the "Select" button.

I´ve read that this is possible with ajax and a "ajax-callback.php" file so I´ve tried it with no success.

**This is my ajax-callback.php:**

```
$data1 = $_POST['data1']  ;
echo $data1;

$data2 = $_POST['data2']  ;
echo $data2;

$data3 = $_POST['data3']  ;
echo $data3;
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML to see what data is being sent selected and sent. Also you are missing a closing bracket for document ready function `});` at the end

Comment: I´ve added }); at the end. No changes. I´ve edited my starting post with the tables´ html output.

Comment: alright then the problem is something else to what you have posted here or have told us. This code and `charlietfl` answer should suffice everything for this simple code to work as required. I am sure there is something wrong which is not mentioned here in the question

Comment: Hi for `col1` will have value `<span>1</span>` if you check instead use `currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").find("span").html();` to get value inside `span` tag .Also, try with `get` instead of `post`and change your `php` code accrodingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object to pass to `data` with the keys you want to use in $_POST.

This gives you the various key/values to be sent after jQuery serializes the object internally

Change

```
data: data1, data2, data3;
```

To

```
data: {data1: data1, data2: data2, data3: data3}, //note comma not `;`
```

Comment: I´ve changed this, thank you. But when I click on the select button still nothing happens. No alert and no echo out in the ajax-callback.php.

Comment: Does click event work? Can inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network (F12) and see if what is sent is what you expect , see what request status is (should be 200) and what gets returned if anything

Comment: Strange. The console isn´t showing any output when I´m clicking on the button.

Comment: Is there a form involved wrapping the table and page reloads? Did you find the network tab in console?

Comment: I´ve posted my table in my starting post. The tables´ content comes out of an array which I get with a foreach loop. There is nothing recorded in the network console when I´m clicking the select button.

Comment: There is an extra `echo '<tr>';` at the top  before the loop

Comment: Oh, true. I´ve deleted it. but no changes. I think there is a mistake with the click event.

Comment: Is that table loaded by ajax after the document loads maybe?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Before `$("#myTable").on('click'` try `console.log($("#myTable").length)`. If it's zero change to `$(document).on('click', '#myTable .btnSelect',function(){`

Comment: I´ve tried both. Nothing happens. Not even in the console anything is happening.

Comment: I´ve checked everything again and the mistake was that the jquery script didn´t found the ajax-callback.php file. Now it works. Thanks again.